# ClassCastException: org.dom4j.DocumentFactory cannot be cast to org.dom4j.DocumentFactory in WildFly 13

Tags: jakarta-ee, wildfly, classcastexception, java-ee-7, classloading

I'm experiencing

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.dom4j.DocumentFactory cannot be cast to org.dom4j.DocumentFactory
```

during deployment to WildFly 13.0.0.Final with an application which deploys fine on Payara 4.1.2.181 and 5.181 for which I have specified

```
<class-loader delegate="false"/>
```

in `WEB-INF/glassfish-web.xml`. I assume that the class cast exception is caused by a class loading issue (because two equal classes loaded by different class loaders are considered not identical) which is avoided by `<class-loader delegate="false"/>`, so I assume specifying the equivalent for WildFly is the KISS solution.

There're many terms regarding the (hierarchical) use of classloader in different Java EE servers (because it's not specified by Java EE) and I started reading about WildFly's concept, however I'll express what I'm looking for in GlassFish/Payara terms: avoid the class loading delegation and take dependencies/search and load classes from the deployed WAR first.

[A bloated thread in the JBoss forums about a class cast exception which didn't occur with GlassFish](https://developer.jboss.org/thread/276744) provides a solution which doesn't apply to my application.

Interestingly, not even excluding all transitive dependencies providing `org.dom4j.DocumentFactory` which makes the app effectively non-portable between Java EE servers helps.

Answer (score 1):

I would need to analyze your classpaths to be sure, but I was getting similar error when I was deploying an app that included different version of hibernate than the one included in wildfly. If you are using hibernate, then that's the good point to start investigating. if not then check if maybe some of other of (transitive) dependencies  conflicts with what is included in wildfly.

Comment: I'm starting to think that WildFly doesn't have a classloader isolation like GlassFish/Payara. In this case, I'll stick with Payara since this a crucial feature avoiding unnecessary difficulties when switching servers.